# UIView.animate not Animating

Tags: swift

I am trying to animate UILabel textColor changes using UIView.animate. However, nothing is changing when I attempt to use UIView. Here is my code:

```
titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 104/250, green: 155/250, blue: 121/250, alpha: 1)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
    self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(red:206/255, green: 206/255, blue: 206/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

I expect the color of the label to change to a greenish color and then change back to the gray-ish color it was before. Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Can you post screen record what is showing right now? Does Animation not working ?

Comment: @AmirKhan Yes, the animation is just not working. It's nothing special.

Comment: Got your point. You want a simple color transformation. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textColor` property is not specified as being animatable in Apple developer docs, so I don't think you can do it with a simple `UIView animations` block.

You can use `UIView transition` instead.

**Code:**

```
UIView.transition(with: self.titleLabel, duration: 1.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 104/250, green: 155/250, blue: 121/250, alpha: 1)
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(red:206/255, green: 206/255, blue: 206/255, alpha: 1.0)
        })
```

I hope it will help you. Let me know if you are still having any issue.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(red:206/255, green: 206/255, blue: 206/255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TextColor is not supposed to be animatable in the documentation so you have to perform below animation code.

**Reason**:

The reason that textColor is not animatable is that UILabel uses a regular CALayer instead of a CATextLayer. so you have two options

1. perform animation on CATextLayer
2. Add custom animation layer as given below in the code.

> ```
> let changeColor = CATransition() 
>
> changeColor.duration = 1
>
> CATransaction.begin()
>
> CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
> self.titleLabel.layer.add(changeColor, forKey: nil)
> self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(red:206/255, green: 206/255, blue: 206/255, alpha: 1.0) }
>
> titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 104.0/255.0, green: 155.0/255.0, blue: 121.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
>
> CATransaction.commit()
> ```